# Default Laravel Vapor Memory

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I am going to increase the memory of my Laravel Vapor environment, yet I don't have the `memory` and `queue-memory` settings in my `vapor.yml` file.

I would like to what the default values for `memory` and `queue-memory` in Laravel Vapor so that I don't accidentally decrease the memory.

Comment: Why do you want to increase the memory, when looking through our vapor logs our system is consistent on its memory usage around 200-250 mb with a maximum of 512. Have you noticed the instance crashing etc? In the logs you would also be able to see how much memory they are spawned with if i remember correctly

Comment: @mrhn This is to increase the memory of the queue worker lambda, not the queue itself. Looks like we had too many scheduled tasks.

Comment: But have you checked the logs? my thesis is that the usage of the queue worker will not be the problem as far as what i have seen in our setup.

Comment: @mrhn Yes I have indeed. Not sure what's wrong...

Comment: and does the logs indicate that you are actually running out of memory?